# Misunderstanding function pointer - passing it as an argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to pass a member function of class A to class B via a function pointer as argument.  Please advise whether this road is leading somewhere and help me fill the pothole.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class A{
public:

int dosomeA(int x){
    cout<< "doing some A to "<<x <<endl;
    return(0);
}
};

class B{
public:

B(int (*ptr)(int)){ptr(0);};
};

int main()
{
A a;
int (*APtr)(int)=&A::dosomeA;

B b(APtr);
return 0;
}
```

This brilliant piece of code leaves me with the compiler error:

> cannot convert `int (A::*)(int)' to`int (*)(int)' in initialization

Firstly I want it to compile.
Secondly I don't want dosomeA to be STATIC.

Comment: The concept you have to get is that non-static member functions require an instance of the class to be invoked on. It simply doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers to members are different from normal function pointers. As the compiler error indicates the type of `&A::dosomeA` is actually `int (A::*)(int)` and not `int (*)(int)`.

Inside `B`'s constructor you need an instance of `A` to call the member on using one the `.*` or `->*` operators.

E.g'

```
B(int(A::*ptr)(int))
{
    A atmp;
    (atmp.*ptr)(int);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

You don't have a pointer to a function that returns an int and takes an int.  You have a pointer to a member-function that returns an int and takes an A* and an int.  Not only do you need to fix the type of your pointer, B needs to provide an A* to serve as dosomeA's `this` parameter.

Boost::bind has some functionality meant to simplify using function pointers in general, and they provide support for pointers to member functions.  See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html).